# How I will set the focus to first row in pageload in Telerik radgrid?

Tags: telerik-grid

I have tried the followings :-

1)$find("<%= telerikLocateUs.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[0].get_element().cells[0].focus();   ->**In PageLoad in Javascript**

2)protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items[0].Focus(); 
    } 
-> **In code behind**

But neither is working .I want to focus the first row through javascript in pageload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var gridItems = $find("<%= telerikGrid.ClientID%>").get_masterTableView().get_dataItems();
**gridItems[0].set_selected(true);**